# How can I implement renaming an option in an HTML select?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I want the user to be able to select an option, and to be able to rename this when clicking a "rename" button.

I'm attempting this by nesting an `input type = "text"` inside the selected `option`. However, the `onblur` event in the `input` is not working...

It seems that `select` does not allow nesting HTML elements inside `option`, but it's functionality is ideal... With what structure might I implement something like this, an unordered-list?

---

Here is the HTML:

```
<select id = "asdf" size = "2">
    <option>asdf</option>
    <option>qwerty</option>
</select>

<input type = "button" value = "rename" onclick = "rename();" />
```

...and here is the javascript/jQuery:

```
function rename() {
    if ($("#asdf").length > 0) {
        var selectedText = $("#asdf").find(":selected").text();
        var selectedIndex = $("#asdf").find(":selected").index();
        var options = document.getElementById("asdf").options;

        options[selectedIndex].innerHTML =
           "<input type = 'text' id = 'field' onblur = 'setField(this.value);'" +
           "value = '" + selectedText + "' />";

        function setField(newName) {
            options[selectedIndex].innerHTML = newName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, `option` does not support this, it is only plain text.

Comment: Hmm, whenever I tested it using just options[selectedIndex].innerHTML = "blah" it changes the option's text. I also noticed that it does in fact change the Select's innerHTML to be a button, except I don't see the button in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it --

    It turns out I *was* able to implement this with a `ul` structure, and some rather nasty jQuery.

---

CSS:

```
    #list {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .highlighted {
        background-color: #FFFF00;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<ul id = "list">
    <li>asdf</li>
    <li>qwerty</li>
<ul>

<input type = "button" value = "rename item" onclick = "renameSearch();" />
```

jQuery/javascript:

```
$("#list").on("click focus", "li", function() {
    $(this)
        .addClass("highlighted")
        .siblings().removeClass("highlighted");
});

function renameSearch() {
    $("#list li").each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("highlighted")) {
            //alert(index + ": " + $(this).text());
            $(this).html("<input type = 'text' id = 'renameField' value = '" + $(this).text() + "' />");

            $("#renameField").focus();
            $("#renameField").select();

            $("#list li").on("focusout", "#renameField", function() {
                //alert($(this).val());
                $(this).parent().text($(this).val());
            });
        }
    });
} // end of function
```

jsFiddle  --  http://jsfiddle.net/icampbell2/59YDF/

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the options:

```
for(var i = 0, l = select.options.length; i < l; i++) 
 {
    var option = select.options[i];
    var obj = {};
    if(option.value == "...")
    {
        option.innerHTML = "...";
        obj[option.value] = option.innerHTML;
    }
 }
 return obj;
```

I would put that in a function and pass a value you search and the replacement, or a map. Something like:

```
setOptionText(select, 'value', 'text');
// or
setOptionText(select, {'value': 'text', 'value': 'text', ...});
```

**Reference**: [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement)

Comment: Thank you for the help @Amol, however unfortunately `<option>` will not allow nested HTML...

Comment: I have made some changes please try that.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the user to be able to select an option, and to be able to
>   rename this when clicking a "rename" button.

Unable to find a suitable solution, I wrote the following, which I think works well, and does exactly as mentioned above.  It seems a bit lengthy compared to the previous answers, but it uses no libraries.

It uses an `<input type=text>` for editing the text of a given `<option>`. The `<input>` is sized and positioned on top of the select, and hidden when not actually in "edit" mode (when the input does not have focus).

```js
//Javascript

var D = document;
function E(id) { return D.getElementById(id); }


var WIDGET_NAMES = [0,'Orange','Loud','Steel','Sky','Wheat','','Almond','Oak','Water','Vague'];

var $select_widget  = E('ESL_select_widget');
var $widget_name    = E('ESL_widget_name');
var $rename_widget  = E('ESL_rename_widget');
var $delete_widget  = E('ESL_delete_widget');


function Pad10(number) {
 if ((number * 1) < 10) { var pad = "&nbsp; "; } else { var pad = ""; }
 return pad + number;
}//end Pad10()


$select_widget.addEventListener("change", function() {
 $widget_name.value = WIDGET_NAMES[$select_widget.value];
});


$select_widget.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
 //Yes, both blur() & focus() are needed...
 if(event.keyCode == 13) {
  D.activeElement.blur();
  $widget_name.style['visibility'] = "visible";
  $widget_name.focus();
 }
});


$widget_name.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
 //Yes, both blur() & focus() are needed...
 if(event.keyCode == 13) {
  D.activeElement.blur();
  $select_widget.focus();
 }
});


$widget_name.addEventListener("blur", function(event) {
 $widget_name.style['visibility'] = "hidden";
});


$widget_name.addEventListener("change", function() {
 this.value   = this.value.trim();
 var current_widget = $select_widget.value;
 
 //options count from 0, people count from 1.
 var option = $select_widget.options[current_widget-1];
 option.innerHTML = Pad10(current_widget) + ":: " + $widget_name.value;
 WIDGET_NAMES[current_widget] = $widget_name.value;
});


$rename_widget.addEventListener("click", function() {
 $widget_name.style['visibility'] = 'visible';
 $widget_name.focus();
});


$delete_widget.addEventListener("click", function() {
 var current_widget = $select_widget.value;
 $select_widget.options[current_widget-1].innerHTML = Pad10(current_widget);
 WIDGET_NAMES[current_widget] = '';
 $widget_name.value = '';
});


for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
 $select_widget.options[x-1].value = x;
 if (WIDGET_NAMES[x] == '') { var mark = ''; } else { var mark = ":: "; }
 $select_widget.options[x-1].innerHTML = Pad10(x) + mark + WIDGET_NAMES[x];
}


$widget_name.value = WIDGET_NAMES[$select_widget.value]

$select_widget.focus();
```

```css
/* CSS */

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

input.ESL:focus, select.ESL:focus, button.ESL:focus { box-shadow: 0 0 3pt 1pt #006060 }

select.ESL:-moz-focusring { color: transparent; text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000; }

#ESL_container {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: .5rem;
 border : solid 1px black;
}

#ESL_rename_container {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
}

#ESL_select_widget {
 width  : 12rem;
 margin : 0 0 .5rem 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size  : 1rem;
 font-family: arial;
}

#ESL_select_widget option { text-align: left; padding-left: .2rem;}

#ESL_widget_name {
 position: absolute;
 top     : 1px;
 left    : 2.1rem;
 margin  : 0;
 padding : 1px 0 0 0;
 width   : 9.9rem;
 height  : 1.3rem;
 border     : solid 1px transparent;
 text-align : left;
 font-size  : 1rem;
 font-family: arial;  /** set to same as select_widget. **/
 visibility : hidden; /** visible during rename only    **/
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div id=ESL_container>
 <div id=ESL_rename_container>
  <select id=ESL_select_widget class=ESL>
   <option value=1 ></option>
   <option value=2 ></option>
   <option value=3 ></option>
   <option value=4 ></option>
   <option value=5 ></option>
   <option value=6 ></option>
   <option value=7 ></option>
   <option value=8 ></option>
   <option value=9 ></option>
   <option value=10></option>
  </select><br>
  <input id=ESL_widget_name type=text class=ESL value="" tabindex=-1>
 </div><br>
 
 <button type=button id=ESL_rename_widget class=ESL>Rename Widget</button>
 <button type=button id=ESL_delete_widget class=ESL>Delete Widget</button>
</div>
```